# Two users with read/write access to the same directory

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I want to run a file syncing program and a music server application on a Linux server. The file syncing program monitors and syncs some folders, including the music folder. The music server application monitors the music folder, plays music from it and sometimes modifies the music files or creates new music files or rearranges them.

Clearly, the file syncing program and the music server application should run under two different user accounts for security. I don't want the music server application to have access to other files synced by the file syncing program. So, let's call those users `file-syncing` and `music-server`. However, I want both programs to have read and write access to all files and subdirectories in the music folder. If the music server application modifies a file or creates a new file or directory in the music folder, I want it to be read/write accessible by the file syncing application, and vice versa. How can I use Linux permissions, ACLs, and whatever else means necessary to set this up?